Imported python function works when imported from module 1 but fails when imported from module 2
I have a weird problem I would like to understand. I wrote a simple genetic code to guess the pair of letters "ab". There is a loop that uses a function that generates random candidates as the first step. The function works and is easy to understand, but, it does not work when imported, only in the case it is inside the whole genetic code module. If I write another module with just that function, and I import from there, it works fine.
What the hell is this?
This is the code I use to import the function:
from scratch_2  import generate_random_candidate

print (generate_random_candidate())

This is scratch_2:
import random
import string

target = "ab"
letras = string.ascii_lowercase
tried_candidates = set()

def generate_random_candidate():
    while True:
        intento = random.choice(letras) + random.choice(letras)
        if intento not in tried_candidates:
            tried_candidates.add(intento)
            return intento

So this was what is working totally fine. And this is scratch_1, when I import from there I see the debug function does not work, if I print tried_candidates I see it prints set(), set (), set (), like it is inside an infinite loop. Is it because it calls the function but does not run its code? Is it related with the variable tried_candidates. Shouldn't the very same function work, independently of the module it is stored in?
This is scratch_1, if I import the function from it, it does nothing.

import random
import string
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotly.graph_objects as go
target = "ab"
letras = string.ascii_lowercase
tried_candidates = set()


def generate_random_candidate():
    while True:
        intento = random.choice(letras) + random.choice(letras)
        if intento not in tried_candidates:
            tried_candidates.add(intento)
            return intento


def generate_children(parent):
    hijos = []
    while True:
        intento = parent[0] + random.choice(letras)
        if intento not in tried_candidates:
            hijos.append(intento)
            break
    while True:
        intento = random.choice(letras) + parent[1]
        if intento not in tried_candidates:
            hijos.append(intento)
            break
    return hijos

def evaluate_candidate(candidate):
    score = 0
    if candidate[0] == target[0]:
        score += 1
    if candidate[1] == target[1]:
        score += 1
    """
    if candidate[0] == target[1]:
        score += 0.1
    if candidate[1] == target[0]:
        score += 0.1
    """

    return score

def g ():
    tried_candidates = set()
    population_size = 10
    population = []

    for _ in range(population_size):
        population.append(generate_random_candidate())
    contador = 1

    while True:
        tried_candidates.update(population)
        scores = []
        for candidate in population:
            scores.append(evaluate_candidate(candidate))
        children = []
        Flag = False
        for i, score in enumerate(scores):
            if score == 2:
                Flag = True
                break
            if score == 1 :
                x = generate_children(population[i])
                tried_candidates.update(x)
                children.extend(generate_children(population[i]))

        if len(children) < population_size:
            new_candidates = []
            for _ in range(population_size - len(children)):
                y = generate_random_candidate()
                tried_candidates.update(y)
                new_candidates.append(y)

            children.extend(new_candidates)
            population = children

        else:
            meter = children[population_size:]
            population = children[:population_size]
            tried_candidates.difference_update(meter)

        found = False
        for candidate in population:
            if evaluate_candidate(candidate) == 2 or Flag == True:
                found = True
                return contador

        contador = contador +1

resultados = []
for i in range (100000):
    resultados.append(g())



The function g creates a local variable tried_candidates. Is that intentional?

Why does that matter? Am I not importing just the function? I start to feel not sure about what happens when I import something. Did you reproduce the issue?

Well, you wrote the code and claim that it's "easy to understand". Why aren't you able to answer my simple question? You have three variables called tried_candidates, two of which are global (but in different namespaces), and another which is local to one function. If don't understand why namespaces and the scoping of variables matter, I suggest you consult the documentation on the subject: i.e. Python Scopes and Namespaces.

Please edit the question and show us an actual example where the function does not work as expected, and explain what you expected instead.

The problem is the last three lines in scratch_1. When the import system reads that file it will (try to) execute any code that is not inside a defined function. Remove those lines and it will work.

OldBoy you got it right. THanks a lot. Why does python execute that? Shouldn't it just kind of copy the imported function and then execute only that? Where could I learn about it?

Thanks ekhumoro and John Gordon for taking the time of reading the question and the code. I really appreaciate. At the end, as OldBoy said, that was not the issue.

@pedrorodriguez The interpreter does this as many modules need some initialisation before their functions can work fully. You can read about it in the documentation at https://docs.python.org/es/3.12/reference/simple_stmts.html#from.

The issue here is related to the tried_candidates variable. Since tried_candidates is a set defined at the module level in both scratch_1 and scratch_2, importing generate_random_candidate from one module into another could lead to different instances or behaviors, especially with the set being modified in each call.
Here's the modified code:
# scratch_1.py
import random
import string
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotly.graph_objects as go

target = "ab"
letras = string.ascii_lowercase

def generate_random_candidate(tried_candidates):
    while True:
        intento = random.choice(letras) + random.choice(letras)
        if intento not in tried_candidates:
            tried_candidates.add(intento)
            return intento

def generate_children(parent, tried_candidates):
    hijos = []
    while True:
        intento = parent[0] + random.choice(letras)
        if intento not in tried_candidates:
            hijos.append(intento)
            break
    while True:
        intento = random.choice(letras) + parent[1]
        if intento not in tried_candidates:
            hijos.append(intento)
            break
    return hijos

def g():
    tried_candidates = set()
    population_size = 10
    population = []

    for _ in range(population_size):
        population.append(generate_random_candidate(tried_candidates))
    contador = 1

    while True:
        scores = []
        for candidate in population:
            scores.append(evaluate_candidate(candidate))
        children = []
        Flag = False
        for i, score in enumerate(scores):
            if score == 2:
                Flag = True
                break
            if score == 1:
                x = generate_children(population[i], tried_candidates)
                tried_candidates.update(x)
                children.extend(x)

        if len(children) < population_size:
            new_candidates = []
            for _ in range(population_size - len(children)):
                y = generate_random_candidate(tried_candidates)
                tried_candidates.add(y)
                new_candidates.append(y)

            children.extend(new_candidates)
            population = children

        else:
            meter = children[population_size:]
            population = children[:population_size]
            tried_candidates.difference_update(meter)

        found = False
        for candidate in population:
            if evaluate_candidate(candidate) == 2 or Flag:
                found = True
                return contador

        contador += 1

def evaluate_candidate(candidate):
    score = 0
    if candidate[0] == target[0]:
        score += 1
    if candidate[1] == target[1]:
        score += 1
    return score

resultados = []
for i in range(100000):
    resultados.append(g())

I hope this will help you a little.

Hi Temunel, thanks a lot for taking the time to read the code and write the answer. I really appreciate since I lost like 4 hours with chatGPTs bull*****. The problem was solved deleting the loop outside of functions definitions, as Oldboy said: The problem is the last three lines in scratch_1. When the import system reads that file it will (try to) execute any code that is not inside a defined function. Remove those lines and it will work. –
OldBoy
Commented7 hours ago . I don't know how to close the question.

@pedrorodriguez You can’t close the question no even if you could you shouldn’t, what if someone comes along with an even better solution? But if this answer helped you can accept it using the check mark and upvote it using the up arrow above the check mark.
